# Unable to install my own apks on google glass after the newest update

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, google-glass, google-gdk

I have been coding on google glass for some months. Since the last update I am unable to run my APKs on google glass.

Before, all I had to do was to click "run" in eclipse ADT and it would install the apk I created. Then I could launch it like any other app in google glass.

Now, it sometimes immediately runs it on google glass, but then I can't find the application in the "ok glass" menu.

Furthermore I get this when I re-run it:

```
[2014-05-27 15:12:07 - startarun] Automatic Target Mode: using device '015D984101016020'

[2014-05-27 15:12:08 - startarun] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.

[2014-05-27 15:12:08 - startarun] /startarun/bin/startarun.apk installed on device

[2014-05-27 15:12:08 - startarun] Done!
```

Here is my manifest to a blank activity I created to try to test it:
EDIT: Since I was getting the same answer and it didn't solve my problem, I updated my manifest. I'm still unable to see my apk on the Ok glass menu. Thank you for your help!

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.glass"
            android:required="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.startarun.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MenuTheme" />

        <service
            android:name="com.example.startarun.MainActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/start_run" />
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Google Glass is currently on XE17.2.

Please help me, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I searched for similar questions here before and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was in the originally posted manifest all along, and that development permission is not needed in this case, because its a command and not a trigger.

By accident during cutting and pasting the poster ended up with two instances of the main activity, one is a service and one is an activity, only the activity is needed, as follows:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
        android:resource="@xml/start_run" />
</activity>
```

This gets rid of the runtime error:

> 05-29 10:41:11.912: E/AndroidRuntime(5166): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.startarun.MainActivity: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.startarun.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Service

And it loads and runs when prompted by voice or tap on Glass.

Comment: Mark, thank you for your help, but I did that already to no avail. Do I need to do anything else? Is there any other information I could post to help you help me better? Thank you for your time, I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: Try an explicit uninstall, like adb uninstall com.your.package.name and then reinstall, I have seen that help in the past.  I was helping someone yesterday with this same issue and we ended up blowing away the project and re-importing code and it worked.  A helpful debug tip is, easier than saying "ok, glass, your command" just tap from the ok, glass screen, your item will be listed first if it installed correctly

Comment: Again, thank you so much for your help, Mark. However, I have had this problem with several iterations starting from scratch of the same program. Can I conclude that I am apparently doing nothing wrong with my code? Maybe I should try to re-install ADT or something. Do you have any more tips for me? Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you put your project on github I'll try it on my glass and debug

Comment: Hi Mark! It's my first time using GitHub, so please forgive any silly mistakes I might have made. Is this link all that you need? https://github.com/MoneyPhobic/Start-A-Run.git Thank you!

Comment: That repo is empty, click my profile there is contact info there, lets take this offline (ie lets email until resolution) and post the solution once we find it.  Send me a note through the contact form.  Happy to help, but don't want to spam SO with all this back and forth

Answer (score 0):

Google recently updated Glass GDK and limited usage of [unlisted](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware#unlisted_commands) voice commands.

If you want to start your glassware with your own `ok glass, ...` command, you have to add this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
```

Detailed information here: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware

Comment: I think you are incorrect due to the fact that I am using a listed voice command. I have tried that in the past though. Any other ideas? Thank you for your help.
Edit: I tried to do your suggestion and it still did not work.